# How to write in a text editor using the VB keyword that I created

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I made a keyboard app in Visual Basic but i can't make it write in other text editor apps like Word

[image: my keyword]

```
Public Class keyb
    Private Sub Btn(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
      Handles Button9.Click, Button8.Click, Button7.Click, Button6.Click, Button5.Click, 
      Button48.Click, Button47.Click, Button46.Click, Button45.Click, Button44.Click, 
      Button43.Click, Button42.Click, Button41.Click, Button40.Click, Button4.Click, 
      Button39.Click, Button38.Click, Button37.Click, Button36.Click, Button35.Click, 
      Button34.Click, Button33.Click, Button32.Click, Button31.Click, Button30.Click,
      Button3.Click, Button29.Click, Button28.Click, Button26.Click, Button25.Click, 
      Button24.Click, Button23.Click, Button22.Click, Button21.Click, Button20.Click, 
      Button2.Click, Button19.Click, Button18.Click, Button17.Click, Button16.Click, 
      Button15.Click, Button14.Click, Button13.Click, Button12.Click, Button11.Click, 
      Button10.Click, Button1.Click
        If ShiftR.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat Then
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + sender.text
            ShiftR.PerformClick()
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + sender.text
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Back_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
      Handles Back.Click
        If TextBox1.Text < " " Then
            TextBox1.Text = Mid(TextBox1.Text, 1, Len(TextBox1.Text) - 1 + 1)
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = Mid(TextBox1.Text, 1, Len(TextBox1.Text) - 1)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Clearly I miss something

Comment: take a look at this https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSSoftKeyboard-0a86f914

Comment: you need to use dlls to send the inputs to other apps, when you click the keys here it will stay in your keyboard app

Comment: thanks ,  now -thanks to you- i have a trigger point.  i'll start from there.  hopefully i can do it    